# How to determine the scroll direction of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have spent whole day to figure out the direction of scroll of `ListView` but could not find any solution.
What I want to achieve is movable header of ListView like "Google Now" search, which goes up while scrolling down and comes back as soon as you scroll up.

What I already have tried so far:

Implemented custom ListView overrode `onScrollChanged` but it always gives 0 for all attributes.

Can anyone put me on the right track.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called the `Quick Return` pattern.  Roman Nurik did a blog post that explains how it works and provided sample code to implement it yourself.  You can find that here: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt

Comment: Could you include a working example here on StackOverflow? That link may not stick around, plus SO has support for wiki responses allowing folks to maintain it over time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  You just have to cache the old position and offset and use that to check for direction.  You might want to filter on scrollState as well:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        int position = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
        int offset = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

        if (mPosition < position || (mPosition == position && mOffset < offset) {
             // Scrolled up
        } else {
             // Scrolled down
        }
        mPosition = position;
        mOffset = offset;
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't this something onScrollChanged should be providing, instead of zero all the time?

Comment: Also, onScrollStateChanged isn't called while you are scrolling, but onScroll is.